# Trying to learn to install Perl module

Tags: perl, module, perl-module

I have been using Perl for about 4 hours. Suffice to say, I don't know anything. However, I'm trying to run a file someone else wrote. They sent me the .pl file and a .pm module that it needs to run. I'm stuck trying to get the module installed.

When I run the file:

```
$ C:\Users\NAME\perl C:\location\reliability.pl
```

I get this:

> Can't locate Krippendorff.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Krippendorff module) (@INC contains: C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/lib) at C:\location\reliability.pl line 4.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\location\reliability.pl line 4.

Since I don't really know what I'm doing, I'm struggling to figure out how to install the .pm file to a directory. I tried installing from cpan, but I think that only works for modules hosted on that site. I don't know the language well enough to interpret other posts.

Can someone explain what I need to do like I'm 5 so I can get this code running? I'm using Strawberry, if that helps. TIA!

Answer (score 3):

It depends where you put the Krippendorff module.  If it is in the same directory try:

```
perl -I C:\location\ C:\location\reliability.pl
```

The `-I` is the include directory to look at for additional modules like Krippendorff.

You don't say were you installed Krippendorff or how which would be useful.

Comment: Adding `use FindBin qw( $RealBin ); use lib $RealBin;` to the script will have the same effect.